# make bold if span contains uppercase with PHP

Tags: php, preg-replace, uppercase

I want to span tags which containing all uppercase text to bold. 
this codes makes only first word.

```
$mystring = '<span> BLABLABLA BLA BLA </span><span>bla bla blabla</span><div>bla bla</div>';
preg_replace("/<span>([A-Z]{2,})*/", "<b>\\1</b></span>",$mystring);
```

thank you
i want result as `<span><b> BLABLABLA BLA BLA </b></span><span>bla bla blabla</span>`
not:original strings has too many html tags inside

Comment: Please specify what your input is and what output exactly you are expecting.

Comment: <span> BLABLABLA BLA BLA </span> something like that... result must be" <span><b> BLABLABLA BLA BLA </b></span>".... it makes " <span><b>BLABLABLA</b></span> BLA BLA </span>"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your solution:

```
$myString = '<span> BLABLABLA BLA BLA </span><span>bla bla blabla</span><div>bla bla</div>';

$myString = preg_replace("/<span>([A-Z\s]+)<\/span>/", "<span><b>\\1</b></span>",$myString);

echo $myString;
```

will match each and every word and will output

```
<span><b> BLABLABLA BLA BLA </b></span><span>bla bla blabla</span><div>bla bla</div>
```

Comment: <span> BLABLABLA BLA BLA </span> something like that... result must be" <span><b> BLABLABLA BLA BLA </b></span>".... it makes " <span><b>BLABLABLA</b></span> BLA BLA </span>"

Comment: thank you but my string comes from database... it has many tags in it.(<div>, <table> etc)  and spans also .... some spans text are only uppercase. i want only these spans bold.

Comment: @mgunduz then I suggest you edit your question and specify how the input exactly looks and how exactly you expect it to look. We can't play "try and guess" here, endlessly editing answer based on new portion of information you decide to post in the comments

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
preg_replace("~<span>([A-Z\s]+)</span>~","<span><b>$1</b></span>","<span>HELLO WORLD</span>");
```

This will output :

```
 <span><b>HELLO WORLD</b></span>
```